# IBAction button working on iPhone 4s, but not on the iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an IBAction button that executes the proper code on an iPhone 4s. When I test it on a 5s, however, the button does not work at all. The button appears in the view, and gets highlighted when selected, but it doesn't push data to the server as expected, like it does with the 4s. Any insights as to why?

```
- (IBAction)addLocation:(id)sender
{
    [self.locationButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self createLocation];
    CLLocation *location = self.locationManager.location;
    if(!location)
    {
        return;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude     longitude:coordinate.longitude];
    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Location"];
    [object setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"location"];
    [object setObject:self.recipient forKey:@"recipient"];

    [object saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(succeeded){
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Location was sent!"message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];
        }
    }];
}
```

**EDIT**

So now the 4s isn't working either. I'm not sure if that's good or bad, but they're both in the same boat now. I'm no longer being prompted to enable location services, so there may be a problem there. I'll post the solution when I find it.

**EDIT 2**

So I finally got the code working for both iPhones. It turns out that there was a problem with initializing the locationManager in the first place. That still doesn't explain why the code worked with the 4s for a brief period of time, but regardless at least the problem seems to be fixed now.

THANKS TO ALL THOSE WHO PROVIDED A POSSIBLE SOLUTION! I APPRECIATE YOUR TIME!

Comment: Can we please take a look at your code? And, can you please check if your iPhone 5s has internet connection?

Comment: certainly. I've added the code to my post. I'm trying to send location data to a Parse backend. Like I said, the 4s works perfectly, and data browser receives the data. The 5s on the other hand does not work at all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say doesn't work does it actually make it into the method and it just isn't doing anything within the method itself or does the method never get hit? Please can you stick a break point on the very first line and see if you hit the method, because if you do hit the method then it is a completely different problem from just an `IBAction` not working

Comment: I do hit the method by breaking on the first line, although I can never seem to break on the alertview. The furthest down I can break is the CLLocationCoordinate2D line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using separate xib or storyboard for iPhone4s and iPhone5s? If yes please check that your IBAction for the UIButton is connected are not from iPhone5s xib or storyboard.
May be IBAction is connected with iPhone4s UI but not with iPhone5s UI. Please recheck it.

Comment: No, i'm using the same storyboard for both 4s and 5s. The IBAction is connected correctly.

Comment: are u using any GestureRecogniser on View?

Comment: No, no gesture recognizer. I can literally plug the 4s in and have it work, then plug the 5s in and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the UI screenshot where button is place?

Comment: well, now the 4s isn't working either. Which I guess is either good or bad, haha....button location is located in the top left corner using auto layout. Appears in the same place in both views. It might be my code, as i'm not being prompted to enable location services when I sign up a new user now.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with alertView,
try this

```
[alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

instead of
    `[alertView show];`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. The code isn't wrong, it works for the 4s, but it still doesn't make the 5s work. Thanks for the response!

Comment: The reason this didn't resolve the problem is because the only difference between just doing `[alertView show]` to doing it with `performSelectorOnMainThread:` is that `performSelectorOnMainThread` ensure that `show` is called on the main thread. If `[alertView show]` wasn't running on the main thread you would get a crash not the button just not working.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1) Try to check if you do have `location` object and if your are passing your `if` statement after getting the `location` object. Maybe, on iPhone 5s location service is disabled, or, you didn't allow your app to use location services?

2) In the completion block of you `PFObject` instance, try to check for the error. Maybe, saving task is completed with error?

While these suggestion are not the answer to your question, they might help you to solve the problem.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try them out. I appreciate you taking the time to look at it!